# Angular chat pagination scroll position

Tags: angular, scroll, chat

I'm doing a chat in angular.
When a User scrolls to the top, the new messages are loaded and placed above.
The problem I'm facing is the position of the scroll bar.
When the new messages are loaded it stays on the top.
What is the best way to move it to a new position.
The messages are lazy loaded from the server when a user scroll to the top.

```js
    fromEvent(this.scroll?.nativeElement, 'scroll').pipe(
      map((scroll: any) => scroll.target.scrollTop),
      tap(st => {
        if (st === 0) {
          // event to load new messages...
        }
      })
    );
```

This is how I'm detecting scrolling to the top.
When new messages are loaded the scrollHeight changes. Do I need somehow to compare old and new or is there a better way to move the scroll bar to a new position?

Comment: If you want to stay at the correct sctroll position, you will have to move the bar when new items are loaded from the server. You can calculate this using the current scroll position, the number of messages and the lineheight of the chat messages.

Comment: Messages can be different sizes, and they are grouped by date so I have that height as well, but I don't know when I will have that element